# How to create a global Handler with React & AXIOS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I'm using ReactJs & AXIOS in this project and i want to make a global error handler without passing by everywhere the request to add catch to it .
I've a service gathering all the requests and I'm creating a new instance of it and use it

```
import Axios from 'axios';
import { getSiteId } from '../helpers';

export class BaseService {
  baseRoute;
  promise;
  constructor() {
    let siteUrl = (process.env && process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL) || '';
    this.baseRoute = `${siteUrl}/api/v1`;

  }

  async create(item) {
    return await Axios.post(`${this.generateURL()}/`, item, {
      ...this.configuration,
    })
      .catch(error => {
        return this.errors(error);
      });

  }
  async update(item, id) {
    return await Axios.patch(`${this.generateURL(id)}`, item, {
      ...this.configuration,
    });
  }
  async filter(query) {
    return await Axios.get(`${this.generateURL()}`, {
      ...this.configuration,
      params: query,
    });

}
```

creating a new instance like so

```
let service= serviceFactory.getInstance();
```

Then access any function

how to do a global handler adding .catch to every request and render component for example modal
from global place , and not to pass to every place i use the functions at

Answer (score 6):

You could use `Axios.create()` method. An example from the official documentation.

```
export const instance = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://some-domain.com/api/',
  timeout: 1000,
  headers: {'X-Custom-Header': 'foobar'}
});
```

Now you can export it to use anywhere like this.

```
import { instance } from './service'
```

OR with Common JS

```
const { instance } = require('./service')
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked, error boundry in react. That wrapper component can be wrppaed your whole component and catch any uncatched jS error/exections ans show any fallback UI.

https://reactjs.org/docs/error-boundaries.html

Comment: It's unclear how this helps the question posed